# how to calculate this infinite integral of infinite product of cosine

Tags: analysis, integration

What is the value of this nontrivial itegral:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \left( \prod_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \cos \frac{x}{n}\right) \, \mbox d x$$

I don't know if there is nice closed answer with known constants.

Comment: Some thoughts: By Viete's formula we have $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \cos\frac{x}{2} \cdot \cos\frac{x}{4} \cdot \cos\frac{x}{8} \cdots =\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \cos\frac{x}{2^n}$. From here you just have to evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} =\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I know this, but in denominator I have linear $n$ instead of exponantial $2^n$

Comment: Of course one can numerically evaluate the problem and thus obtain $0.785381$. I'm not sure if this is any otherwise known number... Maybe we should call it the user13763-number.

Comment: It will be cool if it were $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: I am kind of sure of all the digits. So it is close to $\pi/4$ but not exactly $\pi/4$. There is for sure a reason for that.

Comment: Just to be sure, but I think if you are asking this question you are aware of http://www.ams.org/notices/201110/rtx111001410p.pdf (section "Limits of computation"). The similar integral is the first term in the expansion of $\frac{\pi}{8}$. This expansion is quite good --- the first term gives 42 correct digits. Follow the references there too, it might help.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thank You. Following references it is proved that the value is strictly less than $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginning of an answer.  Use these:
$$\begin{align}
\cos x &= \prod_{k=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2k+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)
\\
\frac{\sin x}{x} &= \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2 \pi^2}\right)
\end{align}$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &:= \prod_{n=1}^\infty \cos \frac{x}{n} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2k+1)^2n^2\pi^2}\right)
\\ &= \prod_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2k+1)^2n^2\pi^2}\right) = \prod_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{2x}{2k+1}}{\frac{2x}{2k+1}} .
\end{align}$$
We have to check that the order can be reversed.

Now (at least for the first few $K$)$^*$ I get
$$
\int_0^\infty \prod_{k=0}^K \frac{\sin\frac{2x}{2k+1}}{\frac{2x}{2k+1}}\,dx
= \frac{\pi}{4}
$$
exactly.  If we can find the right limit theorem, perhaps also
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \prod_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{2x}{2k+1}}{\frac{2x}{2k+1}}\,dx
= \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

$^*$ **added** No, the answer $\pi/4$ is only true up to $K=6$, but fails for $7$ and up.

Comment: [This](http://web.cs.dal.ca/~jborwein/sinc-sums.pdf) might be related.

Comment: @GEdgar:We know now that the result will be less than π/4. I wonder if a value can be found  that the integral result is bigger than the value. Thus the result can be narrowed and be bordered with 2 values. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @Fabian: Yes, exactly (4) and (5) of that paper.

Comment: @Mathlover: Why do we know it is less than $\pi/4$?  These integrands are not nonnegative, so we don't know they decrease with $K$...???

Comment: I just read the user13763's comment above.